# How to loop through months using Joda-Time?

Tags: java, loops, jodatime, treemap

Before I mostly had to loop between days in a certain period and I used loops like this:

```
for(LocalDate iDate = gv.firstDate; iDate.isBefore(gv.lastDate); iDate = iDate.plusDays(1)) {
   ...
}
```

Now I have a `TreeMap` like this:

```
TreeMap<LocalDate, ArrayList<Email>> dates;
```

I want to loop over all months from `gv.firstDate` to `gv.lastDate` and get all `Email`s that are within that month.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this using Joda-Time?

edit:

Having it combined with this will be great, so now get from emails from the dates TreeMap.

```
    for(int y = 2004; y < 2011; y++) {
        for(int m = 0; m < 12; m++) {
            // get all of that month
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using a TreeMap you could use method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap%28K,%20boolean,%20K,%20boolean%29

```
NavigableMap<K,V> subMap(K fromKey,
                         boolean fromInclusive,
                         K toKey,
                         boolean toInclusive)
```

Returns a view of the portion of this map whose keys range from fromKey to toKey.

If the keys defining the interval are not guaranteed to be in the map you can get a map containing only the values you want by doing

```
for(List<Email> emails : dates.tailMap(gv.firstDate).headMap(gv.lastDate).values()) {
   for(Email email : emails) {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: It depends on the data set. If the interval does not always correspond to existing keys it is possible to use the headMap and tailMap methods.

Comment: I think this won't work, as `gv.firstDate` and `gv.lastDate` might not be present in the set of keys.

Comment: I can't check the TreeMap code right now to see if these methods really support keys not present in the map, but even if it does not, the floorKey/ceilingKey methods permit to get the corresponding key present in the map. It avoids passing through all the entries in the map, effectively using TreeMap advantages over a HashMap.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something similar to this:

```
for (Map.Entry<LocalDate, ArrayList<Email>> entry : dates) {
    if (entry.getKey().isBefore(gv.firstDate())) {
        continue;
    }

    if (entry.getKey().isAfter(gv.lastDate())) {
        break;
    }

    // process the emails
    processEmails(entry.getValue());
}
```

If you have the freedom to use Google Guava, you can do something like this:

```
Map<LocalDate, ArrayList<Email>> filteredDates = Maps.filterKeys(dates, new Predicate<LocalDate>() {
    public boolean apply(LocalDate key) {
        if (entry.getKey().isBefore(gv.firstDate())) {
            return false;
        }

        if (entry.getKey().isAfter(gv.lastDate())) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
});

// process the emails
processEmails(filteredDates);
```

Comment: Consider creating a subMap (or tailMap/headMap), eventually using ceilingKey/floorKey method to get the keys in map for the interval. It will avoid iterating on each map entry by taking advantage of TreeMap-specific features.

Comment: Thanks, the Guava way looks promising. I only get a bunch of errors, one of them is that void cannot return values.
Also shouldn't there be a processEmails function? And how can i give the first and last date? gv.firstDate is like somewhere in 2004 and gv.lastDate somewhere in 2011 and i still need to cycle threw each month between.

Comment: @clankill3r I think Guillaume's solution using `headMap` and `tailMap` makes more sense: it's more concise and should be faster. Regarding the void error, it was a mistake on my part. The `apply` function should return `boolean`. And you should write processEmails yourself.